How to write a proper unmarshal for interface{} for AWS ION?
I have the following structs
type foo struct {
    DontCare string `ion:"dontcare" json:"dontcare"`
    Payment MetaDataPayment      `ion:"payment" json:"payment,omitempty"`
}

type MetaDataPayment struct {
    Data interface{} `ion:"data" json:"data"`
    Type string      `ion:"type" json:"type,omitempty"`
}

Data can be 2 different structs depending on Type ( typeA ou typeB )
type TypeA struct {
    Invoice string `json:"invoice"`
}

type TypeB struct {
    Reference string `json:"reference"`
}

I try to work with func (u *MetaDataPayment) UnmarshalIon(r ion.Reader) error
to properly cast TypeA / TypeB , by default it will the data interface will be a map[string]interface{}.
This is trivial to do with unmarshalJSON but I was unable to properly do it using UnmarshalIon.

Implement the Unmarshaler interface:
func (m *MetaDataPayment) UnmarshalIon(r ion.Reader) error {
    ...
}

